# Table Row Description

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      col1
    </th>
    <th>
      col2
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>field1</td>
      <td>field2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">The above row is number 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>field3</td>
      <td>field4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">The above row is number 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**What I want?**
Well I have this HTML code.
I want to put row description but without the use of a useless TR tag.

**Reason:**
I am sorting on the basis of column.
The column value is integer , and when I sort, all row description comes at bottom and field rows are sorted on top. But the row description should be attached to parent row.

**Question:**
How to attach it, so that after sort the table on basis of column, rows descriptions don't get spoiled ?

Comment: Please remove "I want"... we're to help, not write your code. (See [ask])

Comment: what are you using to sort, otherwise i'd just be writing your code?

Comment: You would have to sort in groups of two rows to maintain the header row, go ahead and attempt this, then let us know how you got on and post your JS.

Comment: @ evolutionxbox I am sorry I didn't mean that. I was just trying to be clear.

@ krisp to sort the column, like excel sheet

@G0dsquad sorry I don't understand it

Comment: What is the javascript code you are using for sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an amazing solution, but you can try in this way:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      col1
    </th>
    <th>
      col2
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        field1
      </td>
      <td>field2</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          description
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>field3</td>
      <td>field4</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          description
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
table,
thead,
tbody,
tr {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

table {
  width: 130px;
}

thead {
  height: 30px;
}

th,
td {
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

tr {
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

tr td:last-child {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4xbbzzg5/

Comment: kind of hack to manipulate css, but this seems to be the best solution for now